# SSL error for 4.1 and above device

Tags: android, ssl

I am facing problem for 4.1 and above android devices when I am trying to call my web services. I have converted my .cer file to bks and using the following code:

```
  KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
  InputStream in = c.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);

  trusted.load(in, "password".toCharArray());


 TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
 trustManagerFactory.init(trusted);

 KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
 kmf.init(trusted, "password".toCharArray());

 SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
 context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tm, null);



  URL request = new URL(URL);

  urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) request.openConnection();


  urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

  urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

  urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

  urlConnection.setReadTimeout(200000);


  urlConnection.connect();

  InputStream ina = urlConnection.getInputStream();

  BasicHttpEntity res = new BasicHttpEntity();

  res.setContent(ina);

  HttpResponse resp = new BasicHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1,
                urlConnection.getResponseCode(), "");
  resp.setEntity(res);

  HttpEntity responseEntity = resp.getEntity();

  InputStream data = responseEntity.getContent();
```

This code work on 4.0 and below device but for 4.1 in response I am getting "**403 forbidden error**".

Unfortunately I am not able to find where I am going wrong, any help appropriated.

Answer (score 0):

What's in `trusted`? If you don't require client authentication, you don't need to build a `KeyManagerFactory`, simply pass `null` as there first parameter to `context.init()`.

Comment: "trusted" is my keystore. Updated my code. When I am passing KeyMangerFactory as null to context.init() I am getting FileNOtFound.

Comment: What's in the file? Certificates only or keys as well?

Comment: File is only my certificate

Comment: Then you only need `context.init(null, tm, null);`

Comment: `SSLContext` doesn't deal in files, so you have some other problem. Post stacktrce and try to debug your program.